# Langchain Flask API : Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: flask, langchain

I created a question-answering system using Langchain and want to expose it via an API to get input from the user(i.e. webpage link and question regarding it). When I run and open the link in browser, I get the error : {"error":"415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."}

All the code is below:

**Python**

```
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
    from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
    from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
    from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
    from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    import os
    from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = ''


    app = Flask(__name__)
    run_with_ngrok(app)
 
    def load_page_data(webpage_link):
      #Load the web page content
      loader = WebBaseLoader(webpage_link)
      return loader.load()

    def process_page_content(page_data):
      #Process the web page content
      text_splitter = 
  RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500, chunk_overlap=0)
      all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(page_data)
      return all_splits
 
    def create_vectorstore(all_splits):
      #Create a vectorstore from processed documents
      vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=all_splits, 
      embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings())
      return vectorstore

    def create_qa_chain(vectorstore, user_question):
      #Create a QA chain for question answering
      template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer 
      the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just 
      say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer. Use 
      five sentences maximum and keep the answer as concise as 
      possible. Always say "Thanks for asking!" at the end of the. 
      answer.
      {context}
      Question: {question}
      Helpful Answer:"""
      QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

    llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)

    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
    )

    # Get the answer to the user's question
    result = qa_chain({"query": user_question})
    answer = result["result"]
    return answer


@app.route('/api/question_answer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def question_answer():
    try:
        data = request.json
        webpage_link = data['webpageLink']
        user_question = data['userQuestion']

        print(webpage_link)
        print(user_question)

        page_data = load_page_data(webpage_link)
        all_splits = process_page_content(page_data)
        vectorstore = create_vectorstore(all_splits)
        answer = create_qa_chain(vectorstore, user_question)

        return jsonify({"answer": answer})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**My HTML file looks like this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Page Question Answering</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Web Page Question Answering</h1>
    <form id="qaForm" method="POST">
        <label for="webpageLink">Web Page Link:</label>
        <input type="url" id="webpageLink" name="webpageLink" required><br><br>

        <label for="userQuestion">Your Question:</label>
        <input type="text" id="userQuestion" name="userQuestion" required><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Get Answer">
    </form>

    <div id="answerContainer">
        <h2>Answer:</h2>
        <p id="answer"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("qaForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var webpageLink = document.getElementById("webpageLink").value;
            var userQuestion = document.getElementById("userQuestion").value;

            // Send the data to the Python script
            fetch("/api/question_answer", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ "webpageLink": webpageLink, "userQuestion": userQuestion }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Display the answer
                document.getElementById("answer").innerText = data.answer;
                document.getElementById("answerContainer").style.display = "block";
            })
            .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to get a webpage link and a question on it as inputs and then get an answer using the qa chain, without exposing it to the API, the chain is working fine so there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure where you are hosting your webpage, you are getting CORS error which you can see on browser's devtool console.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

for example, if you open it from a browser, adjust to add full page on the webpage

```
// Send the data to the Python script
            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/question_answer", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ "webpageLink": webpageLink, "userQuestion": userQuestion }),
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }

            })
```

you have two options to fix it

1. install `flask-cors` and the add following

```
#simple app added
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # add CORS , simple app
```

2. add HTML(index.html in templates folder) as your home page on flask app.

```
from flask import render_template

# simpleapp code
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

after fix
Note: you might need to work on llm results :)

[image]

Comment: It finally worked! Thanks a lot, I added the HTML as home page. I was running it on Colab due to dependency issues on my local and it was getting a bit difficult to run an API on it.